# Converting a do while code to methods JAVA

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, do-while

I'm studying engineering at school and part of the course is to complete Computer Programming 1, which I am currently undertaking. I have been finding it very challenging seeing as I have no prior programming experience, especially this week.

The goal of this weeks quiz/assignment is to convert the code we made last week into methods and only perform 2 calls (not that I know what that means). We are learning Java and I have a textbook here that I have been getting help from up until now but I don't find the examples they display very helpful. I will paste my code below and if anyone can help me with how to convert it into methods I would hugely appreciate it!! Thanks

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String session = "C";

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Assignment Manager");
    System.out.println("This application will allow you to track your assignment across       all your topics. It will keep track of the number of assignments, the due dates, their weighting, if they are group based and who is in your group. You will be able to log your progress with the assignment and calculate your current grade for specific topics");
    System.out.println("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+");
    System.out.println("This program was created by <<wfeffe>>");
    System.out.println("<<11th March 2014>>, for the CP1 topic in Semester 1 2014");
    System.out.println("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+");
    System.out.println(" ");
    int score;
    do {

        do {
            System.out.println("Display menu: ");
            System.out.println("      0. Add a new topic");
            System.out.println("      1. Add a new assignment to an existing topic");
            System.out.println("      2. Record a result for an existing assignment");
            System.out.println("      3. Quit");
            score = input.nextInt();
        } while (score > 4 || score < 0);
        do {
            System.out.println("Display menu: ");
            System.out.println("      0. COMP1001");
            System.out.println("      1. COMP1002");
            System.out.println("      2. COMP1003");
            System.out.println("      3. COMP1004");
            score = input.nextInt();
        } while (score >= 4 || score < 0);

        if (score == 0 || score == 1) {
            double gradeTotal = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                do {
                    System.out.println("Enter score for assignment " + i + " from 0-100: ");
                    int grade = input.nextInt();
                    if (gradeTotal >= 0 && gradeTotal <= 100) {
                        gradeTotal += (grade * .25);
                    }
                } while (!(gradeTotal >= 0 && gradeTotal <= 100));
            }
            System.out.println("Total is : " + gradeTotal);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Enter all ten assignments: ");
            double gradeTotal = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
                do {
                    System.out.println("Enter score for assignment " + i + " from 0-100: ");
                    int grade = input.nextInt();
                    if (gradeTotal >= 0 && gradeTotal <= 100) {
                        gradeTotal += (grade * .1);
                    }
                } while (!(gradeTotal >= 0 && gradeTotal <= 100));
            }
            System.out.println("Total is : " + gradeTotal);
        }
        System.out.println("Do you wish to continue or end session? (C to continue)");
    } while (input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("C"));
}
```

}

Comment: what progress do you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

What they mean by converting it into methods is placing code within methods, then calling those methods.

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        method1();
        method2();
    }

    private static void method1() {

    }

    private static void method2() {

    }
}
```

Im not sure if youre supposed to used static. If not, you need to look into creating instances.

Right now, everything is in your main method. Im sure the goal is to move your code into 2 seperate methods (depending on how your cose processes), then call those methods from thw method method.

Chances are, you are going to need to make reference variables (for your Scanner and possibly other things), so you can access it from multiple methods. (make current local variables like scanner field variables if needed)

Answer (score 0):

A call is when you direct the program to enter or execute some method:

```
System.out.println();
          ^^^^^^^^^^^ This is a call to the println() method
```

What your teacher seems to be asking you to do is *factor* your code into methods. I will try to help you factor out some of your code into methods, but I will *not* do any writing for you.

Factoring is a process that works somewhat like factoring a mathematical expression. In general, you can identify a piece of code for factoring out if you see repetitive sections of code that all do the same task, or very similar pieces of code that only differ in similar places. For example, you have:

```
int grade = input.nextInt();
if (gradeTotal >= 0 && gradeTotal <= 100) {
    gradeTotal += (grade * .25);
}
```

I can see at least one other place where this is repeated very nearly verbatim, with only one difference. This would be a good candidate for factoring, perhaps into a method which has this code but replaces the different spot with a variable. Maybe you can even factor some code beyond the code I mentioned.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

They just want you to extract the methods out and call them.

You can create a new scanner in each method or you can just declare it as a variable of your overall class and use it there.

So you would do this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            method1();
            method2();

            //...
            //other code here
            //...

        } while (input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("C"));

    }


    public static void method1()
    {
        int score;
        do {
            System.out.println("Display menu: ");
            System.out.println("      0. Add a new topic");
            System.out.println("      1. Add a new assignment to an existing topic");
            System.out.println("      2. Record a result for an existing assignment");
            System.out.println("      3. Quit");
            score = input.nextInt();
        } while (score > 4 || score < 0);
    }

    public static void method2()
    {
        int score;
        do {
            System.out.println("Display menu: ");
            System.out.println("      0. COMP1001");
            System.out.println("      1. COMP1002");
            System.out.println("      2. COMP1003");
            System.out.println("      3. COMP1004");
            score = input.nextInt();
        } while (score >= 4 || score < 0);        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, line 22 (including spaces) needs to have >= 4 not just > 4.  (Yes the cut of code was on purpose).

What you want to do is have one call that prints out all the menu stuff and returns the int "score".

```
private int displayMenu() {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String session = "C";

System.out.println("Welcome to the Assignment Manager");
System.out.println("This application will allow you to track your assignment across       all your topics. It will keep track of the number of assignments, the due dates, their weighting, if they are group based and who is in your group. You will be able to log your progress with the assignment and calculate your current grade for specific topics");
System.out.println("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+");
System.out.println("This program was created by <<Brayden Paver>>");
System.out.println("<<11th March 2014>>, for the CP1 topic in Semester 1 2014");
System.out.println("+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+");
System.out.println();
int score;
do {

    do {
        System.out.println("Display menu: ");
        System.out.println("      0. Add a new topic");
        System.out.println("      1. Add a new assignment to an existing topic");
        System.out.println("      2. Record a result for an existing assignment");
        System.out.println("      3. Quit");
        score = input.nextInt();
```

} while (score **>=** 4 || score < 0);

```
do {
        System.out.println("Display menu: ");
        System.out.println("      0. COMP1001");
        System.out.println("      1. COMP1002");
        System.out.println("      2. COMP1003");
        System.out.println("      3. COMP1004");
        score = input.nextInt();
    } while (score >= 4 || score < 0);
return score;
}
```

And another that takes score and performs the operation.

```
public void performOperation(int score) {
if (score == 0 || score == 1) {
        double gradeTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter score for assignment " + i + " from 0-100: ");
                int grade = input.nextInt();
                if (gradeTotal >= 0 && gradeTotal <= 100) {
                    gradeTotal += (grade * .25);
                }
            } while (!(gradeTotal >= 0 && gradeTotal <= 100));
        }
        System.out.println("Total is : " + gradeTotal);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Enter all ten assignments: ");
        double gradeTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
            do {
                System.out.println("Enter score for assignment " + i + " from 0-100: ");
                int grade = input.nextInt();
                if (gradeTotal >= 0 && gradeTotal <= 100) {
                    gradeTotal += (grade * .1);
                }
            } while (!(gradeTotal >= 0 && gradeTotal <= 100));
        }
        System.out.println("Total is : " + gradeTotal);
    }
    System.out.println("Do you wish to continue or end session? (C to continue)");
}
```

Then in your psvm:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
int score = displayMenu();
performOperation(score);
//Or performOperation(displayMenu());
} while(input.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("C"));
}
```